# Objective C, difference between n++ and ++n

Tags: objective-c, operator-keyword, increment

In Objective-C, is there any difference between n++ and ++n (eg. used in a for loop)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`++n;` increments the value of `n` **before** the expression is evaluated.

`n++;` increments the value of `n` **after** the expression is evaluated.

So compare the results of this

```
int n = 41;
int o = ++n; //n = 42, o = 42
```

with the results of this:

```
int n = 41;
int o = n++; //n = 42, o = 41
```

In the case of loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {/*...*/}
```

however it doesn't make any difference, unless you had something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; x = i++) {/*...*/}
```

or this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; x = ++i) {/*...*/}
```

One could say:

> It doesn't matter whether to use `n++` or `++n` as long as no second (related) variable is modified (based on n) within the same expression.

---

The same rules apply to `--n;` and `n--;`, obviously.

Comment: Ok, the fact is I'm studying the language on a very good book by Kochan: it seems he says it's a matter of style but he doesn't explain the difference. In other languages I used there WAS a difference (the one you point out). He only says "some programmers prefer to put the ++ or -- after the variable name, as in n++ or bean_counter--. This is acceptable and is a matter of personal preference". I found no explanation about the difference. So I asked here.

Comment: Considered I'm reading a chapter about loops, in that context it could make sense.

Comment: In **Objective-C** (or more correctly **C**) there is a difference, just in all C-like languages. What Steven Kochan probably meant was that in 90% of the times it makes no difference. But it's the 10% that can kill you if done wrong, that make it worth doing it consistent in all the other 90% of times, so that you can clearly see where you have an exception and where it does happen to matter for once. (Btw, I extended my answer since you commented on it. Should make things much clearer now.)

Comment: @Lotus: Lemme fix that for ya, n++; Legit question imho, if you take into account your controversial quote from Steven Kochan. (Might want to add that to your question to clarify your question's background and avoid further downvotes? dunno…) Kochan's (imho wrong) statement made a good case for asking, being one of the better known ObjC beginners books, after all.

Comment: @Regexident: the fact is that after your explanation I thought -considerating the context (a chapter about loops)- that Kochan purposedly avoided further explanations, maybe to avoid confusion. Didactically speaking the book is really well written...

Comment: @Lotus: Ah, okay in the very limited case of trivial for loop in/decrementation this is absolutely correct. However as my answer shows it does not apply to for loops in general. Just for those in their most basic form of `for (…; …; i++) {/*...*/}`.

Comment: @Regexident: I don't kwow why, after ten years programming, I still read EVERY chapter of a new book. So, I was reading about trivial loops: maybe the question arose because I (the little finger of the left foot of Kochan) would have written that thing in a different way (sounds so "general"...)...   ;-)

Comment: @Lotus: "sounds so 'general'", my thoughts exactly. But hey, writing a book is hard, after all. And keeping in mind all those things that could potentially confuse the reader is even more so, given that you, being an experienced professional, hardly ever have to think about those anymore. And quite frankly I've seen much worse. :P You had a fair point, though.

Answer (score 3):

++n increments the value before it's used (pre-increment) and n++ increments after (post-increment).

In the context of a for loop, there is no observable difference, as the increment is applied after the code in the loop has been executed.

Answer (score 2):

`++n` and `n++` differ in what the expression evaluates to. An example:

```
int n = 0;
NSLog(@"%d", n);   // 0
NSLog(@"%d", n++); // still 0, increments afterwards
NSLog(@"%d", n);   // 1
NSLog(@"%d", ++n); // 2, because it increments first
NSLog(@"%d", n);   // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In a loop it wont make a difference. Some people say `++n` is faster though

Comment: Show me a loop where any cost difference between ++n and n++ is measurable (if such a difference exists, which is doubtful given modern compilers), and I'll show you an algorithm that is most very likely entirely sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

In Scott Meyers "More Effective C++" Book he makes a very rational case for preferring prefix increment to postfix increment.  In a nutshell, in that language due to operator overloading facilities prefix increment is almost always faster.  Objective C doesn't support overloaded operators but if you have or ever will do any C++ or Objective-C++ programming then preferring prefix increment is a good habit to get into.

Remember that most of the time ++n looks like:

```
n = n + 1
[do something with n]
```

Whereas n++ looks like (if used as intended):

```
register A = n;  // copy n
[do something with n]
n = A + 1;
```

As you can see the postfix case has more instructions.  In simple for loops most compilers are smart enough to avoid the copy if it's obvious that the pre-increment n isn't going to be used but that case devolves to the prefix case.

I Hope this makes sense.  In summary you should use prefix unless you really want the "side-effect" behavior of evaluate then increment that you get from the postfix version.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, 
**--n** decrements the value of n before the expression is evaluated.

**n--;** decrements the value of n after the expression is evaluated.

The thing here to note is when using while loops

For example:

```
n = 5
while(n--) #Runs the loop 5 times
while(--n) #Runs the loop 4 times
```

As in n-- the loop runs extra time while n = 1
But in --n 1 is first decremented to 0, and then evaluated. This causes the while loop to break.